# Oracle 12c Sysdate comparison to textbox date time

Tags: oracle12c, oracleforms, date-conversion, sysdate

Hi All: not sure if I am going about this the right way.

**Working on this in Oracle 12C forms**

I have a textbox that allows entry of date and time. I am struggling with code to compare what is inputted in this textbox to a display item.

If User inputs data in textbox (for example) **Date_Time_of_Exit**: "03-16-2021 08:05 AM" (EST)

And the date and time they entered in textbox is earlier than what is in display item,  **Local_Time**: "03-16-2021 09:30 AM" (CST)
then the error: "Cannot Complete Log Time".

Notes: display item **Local_Time** may have time and date across 4 timezones. So if user inputs a date and time for a record later than the **Local_Time** display item and it is a valid date and time for the display item time zone, it gets added to database, no issue.

...but if the date and time in **Date_Time_of_Exit** is earlier than the date and time shown in display item **Local_Time** (*including timezone difference*) then that's when the error occurs.

- so basically the user may have a valid time in **Date_Time_of_Exit**, but if it is earlier than what is displayed in **Local_Time** then they should get the error.

current code (for display item Local_Time) *note: this is a code snippet, it is part of larger code*

```
:main.disp_local_time:=TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh:mi am');
else
:main.disp_local_time:=TO_CHAR ( (SYSDATE + (v_TIME_ZONE_DIFF / 24 )), 'hh:mi am');
```

current code (for Date_Time_of_Exit)

```
IF :main.Date_Time_of_Exit < SYSDATE THEN
Message ('Date and Time of Exit invalid.');
Message (' ');
display_error;
raise form_trigger_failure;
CALL_INVALID_DATE_TIME_OF_EXIT;
END IF;
```

What do I need to do to the "SYSDATE" in my code? Or is there a better/more efficient way of doing what I am attempting to do?

Thanks for any help/guidance

Comment: You could use systimestamp instead of sysdate. sysdate has no inherent time zone awareness, while systimestamp does.

Comment: @pmdba thanks for the suggestion, but I need something that will "check" what the user inputs and if what they input is earlier than the display item date and time, they get the error message. So if a user inputs 03-15-2-2021 01:15 for EST and the display item says 03-15-2021 12:30 for AST, then the user would see the error